# Swift 3 Socket Issue

Tags: swift, sockets

I am writing a very simple socket based command line tool in Swift 3, but my streams are not calling the delegate methods. For example, when I check if bytes are available, there are bytes available but the delegate method has not been called. Here is my connection code:

```
func connect() {

    print("Socket Connection")

    let ipAddress = "127.0.0.1" as CFString

    let portNumber: UInt32 = 8080

    var readStream:  Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
    var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(nil, ipAddress, portNumber, &readStream, &writeStream)

    self.inputStream = readStream!.takeRetainedValue()
    self.outputStream = writeStream!.takeRetainedValue()

    self.inputStream?.delegate = self
    self.outputStream?.delegate = self

    self.inputStream?.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
    self.outputStream?.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)

    self.inputStream?.open()
    self.outputStream?.open()
}
```

Comment: Can you try with mainRunLoop instead of current.

Comment: I tried that but it had the same result.

Comment: I suggest you go though https://github.com/tidwall/SwiftWebSocket , use this wrapper class, i have used it in 1 my project. it is very durable and robust.

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```
var inputStream:InputStream!
var outputStream:OutputStream!
var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 1024)

func useCFStream() {

    let host:CFString = "news.yahoo.com" as CFString
    let port:uint = 80


    var readStream :Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?;
    var writeStream:Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?;


    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(nil, host as CFString, port, &readStream, &writeStream)

    inputStream             = readStream!.takeRetainedValue()
    outputStream            = writeStream!.takeRetainedValue()

    inputStream.delegate    = self
    outputStream.delegate   = self


    inputStream.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode:.defaultRunLoopMode)
    outputStream.schedule(in:RunLoop.current, forMode:.defaultRunLoopMode)

    inputStream.open()
    outputStream.open()


    let iData                       = "GET /rss/entertainment HTTP/1.1 \n\n"
    var sendData                    = iData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)


    let uData = sendData?.withUnsafeBytes({ (buffer:UnsafePointer<UInt8>?) -> UnsafePointer<UInt8> in

        return buffer!.advanced(by: 0)
    })
    outputStream.write(uData!, maxLength: sendData!.count)

}

func stream(_ stream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {

    if stream === inputStream {

        print("input")

        switch eventCode {

        case Stream.Event.openCompleted:
            //print("input: openCompleted")
             break
        case Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable:
            print("input: HasBytesAvailable")


            inputStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
            while inputStream.hasBytesAvailable {
                _ = inputStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
                let str = String(bytes: buffer, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                print(" \(str)")

            }

        default:
            print("default")
        }
    }
    else if stream === outputStream {

        //print("output")
    }

}
```

can't vouch for code optimisation.
i have not understood withUnsafeBytes and UnsafePointer usage but managed to make it work, if someone have better solution please post.

Comment: This did help. Thank you!